# Can someone explain how this left rotating array code works?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to learn more about arrays and how to rotate them. I stumbled upon a code and I'm trying to figure out how it prints out the rotation correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

 int n = sc.nextInt();

 int d = sc.nextInt();

 int arr [] = new int [n];

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  arr [i] = sc.nextInt();
 }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  System.out.print (arr [(i + d) % n] + " ");   
 }
}
```

I have tried doing the math myself to see how it works, but it doesn't add up and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The n is for the number for integers in the array and d is the number of rotations.

The equation is: (i + d) % n with n = 5, d = 4, and the array being {1,2,3,4,5}

1. (1 + 4) % 5 = 5 % 5 = 0
2. (2 + 4) % 5 = 6 % 5 = 1
3. (3 + 4) % 5 = 7 % 5 = 2
4. (4 + 4) % 5 = 8 % 5 = 3
5. (5 + 4) % 5 = 9 % 5 = 4

The answer that it prints out is 5 1 2 3 4 which is correct, but from what I calculated it should print out as 1 2 3 4 5. How I got this is that from the following calculations it says that 1 should go to index 0, 2 should go to index 1, etc... If you guys can help explain how the code works, that would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  System.out.print (arr [(i + d) % n] + " ");   
 }
```

The array will start from 0 since in the for loop you gave i as 0. so it will start from 0 to 4.

```
(0 + 4) % 5 = 4 % 5 = 5
(1 + 4) % 5 = 5 % 5 = 1
(2 + 4) % 5 = 6 % 5 = 2
(3 + 4) % 5 = 7 % 5 = 3
(4 + 4) % 5 = 8 % 5 = 4
```

Comment: should probably point out that it's ```arr[4%5]``` resulting in 5

Answer (score 0):

First, you collect arrays with the contents `{1,2,3,4,5}`, this means you have 5 indexes with details :

```
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
arr[2] = 3
arr[3] = 4
arr[4] = 5
```

Then you want each index content to be added to the value `d` then modulus `%` with the value `n`.

What's wrong is in your second iteration ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    System.out.print (arr [(i + d) % n] + " ");   
}
```

If you print this `(i + d)% n`, it will produce this :

```
(0 + 4) % 5 = 4
(1 + 4) % 5 = 0
(2 + 4) % 5 = 1
(3 + 4) % 5 = 2
(4 + 4) % 5 = 3
```

So with this command :

```
System.out.print (arr [(i + d) % n] + " ");
```

Actually you are printing :

```
arr[4]
arr[0]
arr[1]
arr[2]
arr[3]
```

So if you want the results that you want, change the second iteration by holding the value of each index of your array with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    arr[i] = (arr[i] + d) % n;
    System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
}
```

This will print `0 1 2 3 4`

Hope this helps